# Simple jQuery show/hide does not work on page but works as a standalone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this simple show hide script in my page without luck. The page has a lot of coding, php and jquery.

I have tested it in a new page , having of course the jquery.js file and it is working properly. However I can not understand why it is not working on my current page. Any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show1").hide();
        $("#showhide").click(function(){
            $("#show1").show();
        });
    });
</script>

<a id="showhide">More...</a>

<div id="show1">
    text
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: It may be because prototype or other js-framworks are used on the bigger site, which also use the $-sign. Try to replace every $ with "jQuery". Additionally, you can add "jQuery.noConflict()" at the bottom of jquery.js

Comment: @HCS-Support tried both but none seems to work

Comment: Maybe more than one ready-function? This may cause problems

Comment: If you have more than one link and are using the same IDs rather naming them differently or using classes, you may have some troubles.